# Почему не получается вставить картинку из json по урлу?

Tags: javascript, json

json

```
 [
    {
    "resultString": "ntcn",
    "resultImg": "./images/img1.png"
},
{
    "resultString": "fgfgf",
    "resultImg": "./images/img2.png"
}

]
```

в пропсах в компонент приходит resulImg как
'./images/img1.png'

и хочу вставить бэкграундом так

```
   <div className={s.root} style={{ backgroundImage: 
  `url(${this.props.resultImg})` }}>
```

раньше импортировал просто так
import Img from './images/img1.png';
и вставлял как

```
 <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${Img})` }}>
```

работало. как из json получить урл?

Comment: а пропсы проверяли? точно приходит то, что нужно? `console.log(this.props)`

Comment: почему -то когда я импортирую картинку оттуда и вставляю, на самом деле урл картинки прсотавляется следующий 
/static/media/img1.png

а если из json,  то соответственно на месте урла  проставляется ./images/img1.png

Comment: прописать напрямую получается нужно /static/media/img1.png?

Comment: как вариант, да. А собираете webpack-ом?

Comment: да. вроде получилось так.

Answer (score 0):

В webpack.config.js есть опции для настройки абсолютных и относительных путей. Как вариант заменить пути в json-е на абсолютные.